# Is there a way to console log/error and return from a function in one line using ES6 syntax?

Tags: ecmascript-6, syntax

I find myself writing code akin to the following quite a bit:

```
const fileEl = document.getElementById("import-style-file-input");
if (fileEl === null) {
   console.error("No file element");
   return;
}
```

Is there a way I could condense lines 3 & 4 into a single line? E.g.

```
if (fileEl === null) log_and_return("No file element");
```

Or do scope limitations make this impossible?

Comment: Probably no pretty way. e.g. `console.error(‘…’) || return` will do it but make your code harder to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `return;` by itself just returns `undefined` anyway, you can return the result of `console.error` which is also `undefined`:

```
if (fileEl === null) return console.error("No file element");
```

Something like this may look strange to another reader, so in any team environment I'd recommend getting opinions from the team members.  But on a purely technical level, it does what you're looking for.

---

If team members want it to look more intuitive, wrapping the same functionality in a custom-named function does the same thing:

```
if (fileEl === null) return log_and_return("No file element");

// elsewhere...
function log_and_return(msg) { console.error(msg); }
```